# How to change color text in button?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void arrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    if (turn == 0)
    {
        button.ForeColor = Color.Green; // Can't change color
        button.Text = "X";
        button.Enabled = false;
        turn = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Text = "O";
        button.Enabled = false;
        turn = 0;
    }
}
```

I used `button.ForeColor = new Color.Green` but when I test X still can't change green color.

How to change color text in button ?

Comment: you need to enable it to see the color change.

Comment: BackColor is change background but I wanna change text

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, WebForms, MVC or anything else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disabled component doesn't effect any graphical changes. It must be enabled to reflect the Color change.

You should use any other condition to check disabled button if you want to keep the graphical changes.

**For Example:**

```
if(button.ForeColor == Color.Green)
    //handle the click event
```

Answer (score 1):

for wpf:

```
private void arrButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                button.Foreground= Brushes.Blue;
            }
```

for Winform:

```
private void arrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```